# detect microsoft office version using javascript

Tags: javascript, ms-office

I have to check whether or not the client pc has MS Office 2007 installed or not.

How can I check this using javascript?

Comment: Is that JavaScript from the browser, or running using the shell script host?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this *from within a browser*. The browser does not allow javascript access to the client computer. It would be a gaping security hole.

Microsoft gets around this by using Active X. There are other browser-to-desktop plugins that could accomplish the same thing.

Javascript, however, is a no-go.

Comment: Don't forget that javascript runs from the command-line using WScript or cscript.exe.  It is possible to do from a non-browser script host.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do this with ActiveX. Something like:

```
var word = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
```

and than check operation result.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this isn't possible.
However, if the client is using Internet Explorer, and has InfoPath installed (which is part of Office), you can check the [user agent](http://www.useragentstring.com/) for `InfoPath.2`. Another option is to check for `MS-RTC LM`  , if they have the Office Live Meeting installed.
This is very limiting, but it just *might* work on a local intranet.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using the following script:

```
try{
var oApplication=new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
if(oApplication){
document.write(oApplication.Version);

if(oApplication.Version == "12.0")
{
document.write("office07 installed");
}

}
}
catch( ex)
{
document.write(" not installed: ");
document.write(ex.message);
}
```

Comment: Note that you have to call `Application.Quit()` after checking the version in Jazzy's solution. If you don't, you'll have a ghost WinWord.exe instance running in the background, with no means of killing it later except for the taskmanager.