# Is there a way to detect if MS Visio, MS Word, or any MS Office app is installed on computer from IE & Chrome?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, ms-office, url-scheme

I have a SharePoint 2019 document library wherein I have a custom JavaScript code to open the MS documents (Word, Excel, Ppt, Visio) in the client application. I am using Office URI schemes for opening the documents in client apps. However, if there is no client application installed on the computer, the Office URI scheme fails without throwing up any error. I want to know if there is a way to check from the browser (IE and Chrome) if a particular MS application (Visio, Word, etc.) is installed on the computer.

P.S. I have tried the ActiveXObject approach, but for some reason, it didn't work for me and, also I want a solution that will be cross-browser compatible and afaik ActiveXObject is supported only on IE.

Answer (score 1):

(Current MSFT employee in Office here. On the team that owns the link invocation handling for the native client side but not the SharePoint or JS side)

The root problem is that the browser object model doesn't give you a result for navigating to the ms-word/etc links. As I understand it that is why the built-in SharePoint open UX has 2 options. One to open in the browser and another to open in the native client. And there is interstitial UX to prompt the user if the file did not successfully open in the native client.

(And, correct, the ActiveX solution will not work even with modern Edge on windows either and is a dead-end technology wise.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ActiveX technology to instantiate Office application as described on the [detect microsoft office version using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700150/detect-microsoft-office-version-using-javascript) thread. But Chrome is not aware of COM technology. So, any code for creating an Office application instance will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but I am looking for a cross-browser compatible solution.

Comment: There is no cross-browser solution for that.